# chart js - bar chart with time scale on Y axis in Hours and Minutes

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, momentjs, duration

I', using chartjs and now i need to render a time duration.

i need to have category on X axis and duration on Y axis.

is there a way to convert a duration on x axe to have:

40 -> 40 minutes

150 -> 2:30 (or some else formatted, but with value on y axe converted on base 60 for conversion of minutes in hours, NOT IN DECIMAL!)

i tried with

```
scales: {

        yAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'minute',
                displayFormats: {
                    hour: 'h:mm:ss a'
                }
            }
        }]

        //
    }
```

witouth success.

this is my full code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("graficotest1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {

    labels: [
          'modo 1',
          'modo 2,
          'modo 13'
         ],
    datasets: [ 

        {
            label: '# Durata reale',
            data: [
              3100,
              615,
              705
            ],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'red'
        },
        {
            label: '# Ore in',
            data: [
              0,
              0,
              465
            ],
            backgroundColor: '#DEF797',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'yellow'
        },

  ]
},
options: {
    scales: {

        //
        yAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'minute',
                displayFormats: {
                    hour: 'h:mm:ss a'
                }
            }
        }]

        //
    },
    //
    title: {
        display: false,
        text: 'stat 1'
    },
    //scaleShowGridLines: false




}
});
```

i need to convert all valures like 3100, 615, 705 (minutes) to hours:minutes in the graph

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I checked in the internet and there is a simple hack to do this, why I use the hack is because if I set the Y-axis to date, the graph does not get rendered and throws an error.

Please find below the configuration used to achieve date Y-Axis.

```
var options = {
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleSteps: 8,
    scaleStepWidth: 1800,
    scaleStartValue: 0,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scaleLabel: function(valuePayload) {
        console.log(new Date(valuePayload.value  * 1000).toISOString());
      return new Date(valuePayload.value  * 1000).toISOString().substr(12, 7);
    },
    multiTooltipTemplate: function(valuePayload) {
      return valuePayload.datasetLabel + " " + new Date(valuePayload.value * 1000).toISOString().substr(12, 7)
    },
    title: {
        display: false,
        text: 'stat 1'
    }
  };
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

The below issue on Github contains nifty method to achieve time axis on Y-Axis.

**GITHUB Issue:** [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2791)

The below fiddle contains the modified code, where the Date Y-Axis is visible,

**JSFiddle:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/123Lcev9/1/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answare my question. I Tried this solution bu it seems to work only with ChartJS v1, i'm using latest release 2.6.0 and the axes formatting is not working with your code.....